# How simplify and expand work in Maple

Tags: maple

When I do:

```
expand(sin(5*u))                (1)
```

The output is:

```
16*sin(u)*cos(u)^4 - 12*sin(u)*cos(u)^2 + sin(u)                (2)
```

If I want it to give me an expression with merely sin(u) in it, I would do:

```
simplify(expand(sin(5*u)), [cos(u)^2 = 1 - sin(u)^2])                (3)
```

The output of (3) is:

```
16*sin(u)^5 - 20*sin(u)^3 + 5*sin(u)                (4)
```

Now, I want to expand tan(4*u). I write:

```
expand(tan(4*u))                (5)
```

The output of (5) is:

```
(4*tan(u) - 4*tan(u)^3)/(1 - 6*tan(u)^2 + tan(u)^4)                (6)
```

I want it to be in terms of just sin(u) and cos(u). The natural thing to do (I suppose) is to write:

```
simplify(expand(tan(4*u)), [tan(u) = sin(u)/cos(u)])                (7)
```

But the output of (7) is just:

```
(4*tan(u) - 4*tan(u)^3)/(1 - 6*tan(u)^2 + tan(u)^4)                (8)
```

Which is the same expression as (6). So, (7) turned out to be useless.

My questions are:

> $1)$ When is this method (putting an identity inside []) useful and what are its limitations?
>
> $2)$ Are there any shortcuts or better methods to work with than this one?

Comment: what does [sin(u)/cos(u)=tan(u)] do?

Comment: Just like what [cos(u)^2 = 1 - sin(u)^2] was supposed to do. Which is, I think, some sort of a command for Maple to replace any cos(u)^2 with a 1 - sin(u)^2. But I am not sure and I don't think that this is precise. This is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wish to substitute `tan(u)=sin(u)/cos(u)` then use either the 2-argument form of the `eval` command (or the `subs` or `algsubs` commands).

```
expr := expand(tan(4*u));           

                                                3
                             4 tan(u) - 4 tan(u)
                    expr := -----------------------
                                        2         4
                            1 - 6 tan(u)  + tan(u)

eval( expr, tan(u)=sin(u)/cos(u) );

                                            3
                         4 sin(u)   4 sin(u)
                         -------- - ---------
                          cos(u)           3
                                     cos(u)
                        -----------------------
                                    2         4
                            6 sin(u)    sin(u)
                        1 - --------- + -------
                                   2          4
                             cos(u)     cos(u)

normal( eval( expr, tan(u)=sin(u)/cos(u) ) );

                                   2         2
                   4 sin(u) (sin(u)  - cos(u) ) cos(u)
                - -------------------------------------
                        4           2       2         4
                  sin(u)  - 6 sin(u)  cos(u)  + cos(u)

simplify( eval( expr, tan(u)=sin(u)/cos(u) ) );

                                             2
                    4 sin(u) cos(u) (2 cos(u)  - 1)
                    -------------------------------
                               4           2
                       8 cos(u)  - 8 cos(u)  + 1
```

This particular substitution for `tan` in terms of `sin` and `cos` can also be made as a conversion. (Here too you could wrap with `normal` or `simplify` just to get a more terse result.)

```
convert( expr, sincos );

                                            3
                         4 sin(u)   4 sin(u)
                         -------- - ---------
                          cos(u)           3
                                     cos(u)
                        -----------------------
                                    2         4
                            6 sin(u)    sin(u)
                        1 - --------- + -------
                                   2          4
                             cos(u)     cos(u)

simplify( convert( expr, sincos ) );

                                             2
                    4 sin(u) cos(u) (2 cos(u)  - 1)
                    -------------------------------
                               4           2
                       8 cos(u)  - 8 cos(u)  + 1
```

Here are some other ways to get your first example's result,

```
examp := expand(sin(5*u));                       

                                 4                   2
        examp := 16 sin(u) cos(u)  - 12 sin(u) cos(u)  + sin(u)
```

If we use the 2-argument `eval` (or `subs`) command and try to substitute for `cos(u)^2` then the `cos(u)^4` will be left untouched. So that's one advantage to using "simplify with subrelations", which what your original code did.

For this example it's possible to substitute for `cos(u)` and use `sqrt`.

```
expand( eval( examp, cos(u)=sqrt(1-sin(u)) ) );

                           3            2
                  16 sin(u)  - 20 sin(u)  + 5 sin(u)
```

But you can also attain your desired result without using either `sqrt` or simplification with side-relations, by using the `algsubs` command.

```
algsubs( cos(u)^2=1-sin(u)^2, examp );

                           5            3
                  16 sin(u)  - 20 sin(u)  + 5 sin(u)
```

There may not be a canonical "simplest" form for expressions like yours. So, as you've seen, invoking `simplify` leaves some decisions up to the system. If your goal is to perform some particular substitutions and obtain a particular form of result then you may be better off choosing particular manipulations.

When I want to retain more control of the substitutions then my own preference is to use 2-argument `eval` where possible, and if that is not satisfactory then to use `algsubs`, and if neither is adequate then to use simplification with side-relations.